# Run query on a button click

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am new to coding and I just need to know how to assign a SQL statement to a onclick button.

The SQL that I have works great and does the job.

```
Select * From fields
where rno ='R1';
```

And this works fine. All I want to do now is attach this SQL to a button on the form to get the same result.
I have ADO Connection, ADO Query, and Datasource plus DBgrid1 all working fine

Thanks

Comment: In the button's OnClick event, assign your SQL statement to the ADOQuery.SQL.Text and then Open the query.

Comment: procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOQuery1.Close;{close the query}
//assign new SQL expression
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('Select *');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('FROM fields.dbf');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('WHERE rno ='R1'');
ADOQuery1.RequestLive := true;
ADOQuery1.Open; {open query + display data}
end;

end.

Comment: [Error] Unit3.pas(45): ')' expected but identifier 'R1' found

Comment: [Fatal Error] WizardFormPro.dpr(7): Could not compile used unit 'Unit3.pas'

Comment: Your quotes are a mess in your SQL. Stop concatenating your SQL and learn to use parameters. Also, don't post code in comments; [edit] your question and put it there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Put in in your button's OnClick event, and open your query there.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM fields WHERE mo = :mo';
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('mo').Value := 'R1';
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Comment: that is fantastic works like a charm. one more question if you don't mind?

Comment: If you need a clarification of what I wrote, sure. If you have a new question, create a new question and ask it there. That's how this site works. :-)

Comment: If I wanted to sort in desending order on a field in that SQL statement like Wght for instants how would I add the sort.

Comment: With an ORDER BY statement, added to the end of the SQL, like `ORDER BY Wght DESC`. This is pretty basic stuff; you might want to find a SQL tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much Ken your a wizard.